# Edit Nav Bar after preformSegue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, navbar

How do I remove the "back" button from my NavigationBar after a

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue", sender: nil)
```

Ok let me explain. I have a profile page embedded in a Nav Bar, You can edit it in an edit page and once you're done it updates the info on Parse and the segue sends you back to the profile page. However the user can still click back and reload the edit page and then again back to the original profile page.

How do I prevent this from automatically populating?

```
@IBAction func doneEditing(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.completeEdit()
}


func completeEdit() {
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()!
    user["Location"] = locationTextField.text

    user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
            println("failed")
        } else {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Edited", sender: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

New Edit ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would try with your code:

```
@IBAction func doneEditing(sender: UIButton) {
self.completeEdit()
```

}

```
func completeEdit() {
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()!
    user["Location"] = locationTextField.text

user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
        println("failed")
    } else {
        navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }
}
```

}

All that I changed is the "AnyObject" to "UIButton" and then I swapped your "perform segue" with "popViewControllerAnimated"

Comment: Upon looking at more of the recent comments in other answers here, I noticed that you are already using an IBAction to call your segue. This means you will only need to replace your `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue", sender: nil)` with `navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`

Comment: I added what my code is. I'm not calling it from a Nav Button but an Any Object.

Edit: Where would I instantiated new VC and View name?

Comment: Is your action hooked up to a UIButton? Or maybe a UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: It went back perfectly without the backbutton and title, but it doesn't show the new data that was given to Parse. Do I just reload the data in ViewDidLoad?

Comment: Yep! Although it would be better to add it into your viewWillAppear.

Comment: Perfect! One final question for the night I swear. Is there an easier way to call the entire class? 

myObject.refresh() <---- Parse Code

But for PFUser, its hard to make it call the entire class so I'm calling all of the columns individually. I don't mind it but I feel that its sloppy.

Comment: Hmm..I don't actually know very much about Parse. I would just post another question to get someone who knows how to use it to answer. Good luck!